# Get a parsable string with carriage returns

Tags: vim

I sometimes use the `string()` function in order to generate parsable strings.

For example, `:echo string("hello world")` shows:

```
'hello world'
```

But if I add real carriage returns into the string, the result becomes unparsable, simply because 
the carriage returns are not transformed.

For example, `:echo string("hello\nworld")` shows:

```
'hello
world'
```

I would have expected:

```
"hello\nworld"
```

Is there a way to get a parsable version of *any* string, without writing a dedicated function?

---

**EDIT**

To be more precise, I need "parsable" strings to be used with the `:execute` command, in order to create customizable mappings. The basic idea is to be able to use the following code, even when there are some CRs in the `a:toinsert` argument:

```
function! InsertMapping(lhs, toinsert)
    let l:rhs = printf('<c-r>=%s<cr>', string(a:toinsert))
    exe 'inoremap' a:lhs l:rhs
endf

" This call is working:
call InsertMapping('<c-r><c-e>', "hello world")

" This one throws an error:
call InsertMapping('<c-r><c-e>', "hello\nworld")
" E492: Not an editor command: world')<cr>
```

Indeed, the last call to `InsertMapping()` will try to execute:

```
inoremap <c-r><c-e> <c-r>='hello
world'<cr>
```

Buf of course, I need to execute instead:

```
inoremap <c-r><c-e> <c-r>="hello\nworld"<cr>
```

*Please note* that I need to keep `<c-r>=` because my real use case is more complex, and needs some function calls; so the mapping can't be simplified like this:

```
inoremap <c-r><c-e> hello<cr>world
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally wrote a dedicated function to stringify a vim string; it's far from perfect, but it will give a "correct" output for all the tested cases. When really nothing at all is special inside the string, it returns a single-quoted string, which may slightly improve performance in some rare cases.

Here is the code:

```
let s:specials = {
    \ "\b":'\b', "\e":'\e', "\f":'\f', "\n":'\n',
    \ "\r":'\r', "\t":'\t', "\\":'\\', "\"":'\"',
\}

function! Stringify(source)
    let output = ''
    let string_is_special = v:false

    for i in range(strlen(a:source))
        let char = a:source[i]
        let ascii = char2nr(char)

        let char_is_special = v:false
        for [key, str] in items(s:specials)
            if char == key
                let output .= str
                let char_is_special = v:true
                let string_is_special = v:true
                break
            endif
        endfor

        if !char_is_special
            if ascii < 32
                let output .= printf('\x%02x', ascii)
                let string_is_special = v:true
            else
                let output .= char
            endif
        endif
    endfor

    return printf(string_is_special ? '"%s"' : "'%s'", output)
endf
```

Here are some quick tests:

```
let tests = [
    \ "simple string",
    \ 'back \ slash',
    \ "carriage \n return",
    \ "utf8 frénçh àccènts",
    \ "\x47\x6e\x75",
    \ "ctrl-w special key: \<c-w>",
\ ]

for s in tests
    echo Stringify(s)
endfor
```

Here is the tests output:

```
'simple string'
"back \\ slash"
"carriage \n return"
'utf8 frénçh àccènts'
'Gnu'
"ctrl-w special key: \x17"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what do you exactly mean "parsable". If you want to use `eval()` to get the original string value, it is working. You see the real linebreak was printed out because of the `echo()` function, it expanded the `\n` as a linebreak.

Give this a try:

```
let a="hi\nworld"
echo a==eval(string(a))
echo a==eval(string("hi\nworld"))
```

both will return `1` (true). So it is "parsable".

If I didn't understand the meaning of your "parsable", please make some example.

Comment: As I wrote to romainl, `JSON.stringify()` in javascript is a good equivalent of what I'm looking for: a function which returns a one-line, parsable vim string.

Answer (score -1):

In Vim, single quotes and double quotes have different behaviors.

Between double quotes, special characters like `\n` are interpreted, so:

```
"hello\nworld"
```

becomes:

```
hello
world
```

and you would have to double the `\` to actually get a `\n`:

```
"hello\\nworld"
```

Between single quotes, special characters are not interpreted, so:

```
'hello\nworld'
```

becomes:

```
hello\nworld
```

All of that is explained under `:help expr-"` and `:help expr-'`.

Comment: Thank you, I know the difference you pointed out, but I don't think this can solve my issue

Comment: It perfectly solves your problem as stated in your initial question.

Comment: I may not be very clear in my initial question (please see my edit), but I'm well placed to know that it doesn't solve my issue: single-quoting or doubling the slash would just insert `hello\nworld`, I don't want that. I just need an equivalent of `JSON.stringify()` in javascript. The problem here is that real CRs result in untransformed real CRs, and can't be parsed in a one-line command (see my edit)

Comment: Your edit completely changed the meaning of your question.